# How to access apache hive tables from Apache Druid.?

Tags: hive, druid

I am trying to access apache hive tables from apache Druid, as I dont see hive plugin/datasource from Druid router UI.

Curious to know where shall we see hive tables from Druid Router UI.?

accessing the apache hive tables from the apache Druid,